# ¿Como obtener el ultimo archivo de varias carpetas en python?

Tags: python, archivo

Tengo una estructura con una carpeta, que contiene varias carpetas y dentro de cada una de esas carpetas tengo varios archivos.

La idea es obtener el ultimo archivo de cada carpeta en una lista, alguna opcion?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura seria tal que asi

Y dentro de cada una de esas carpetas, habria 3,4,5 archivos.

Dejo por aqui la primera aproximación:

```
lista_archivos = glob.glob("Directorio_base/*/*")
print(lista_archivos)
```

Esto me printea todos los archivos, el problema es que necesito el ultimo de cada carpeta.

Comment: Si, realmente estoy usando glob.glob("Directoriobase"/*/* y listo todos los archivos, pero no se como quedarme con el ultimo de cada carpeta.

Comment: Es que el problema viene cuando quiero listarlos todos. Es decir, el codigo con globglob es facil, ahora lo pego.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer una guia para ver otros modos de recorrer directorios, que te dan más control de cada uno de ellos -> https://j2logo.com/python/listar-directorio-en-python/

Comment: `ultimo = {'/'.join(x.split("/")[:-1]): x.split("/")[-1] for x in glob.glob("/home/jorge/bin/*/*")}` te servira para empezar.

Comment: Una pregunta que deberías hacerte, que consideras como "el ultimo archivo". El que archivo sea el ultimo depende del orden en que hagas la consulta.

Comment: El ultimo archivo de la carpeta en función del nombre del mismo. El problema real es que no logro aislar los archivos

Comment: Pues no consigo hacer lo que quiero. Como mucho puedo obtener los archivos de cada carpeta, pero en ningun caso consigo obtener el ultimo de cada carpeta por fecha de creación o por nombre. Es extraño